# the -> macro and partial function

Tags: clojure

Why can't I use a partial function or an anonymous function in a chained call with `->`?

```
(->
    "123"
    seq
    sort
    reverse
    (partial apply str))
=> #<core$partial$fn__4230 clojure.core$partial$fn__4230@335f63af>
```

I would have thought the partial function would be created and immediately applied to the previous function's result, but it's actually returned itself.

A simple chaining of functions with one parameter of course works without problems:

```
(->
    "123"
    seq
    sort
    reverse
    clojure.string/join)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `->` and `->>` are just macros, you can test what `->` expands to with `macroexpand-1` (note the quote ')

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(->
       "123"
       seq
       sort
       reverse
       (partial apply str)))

(partial (reverse (sort (seq "123"))) apply str)
```

So that's why you get a function instead of a string - result is partial of collection (which is a function) returned from `reverse` and `apply` `str` as arguments.

If for some reason you need to apply a funcion in `->`, you should wrap it in parens:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(->
    "123"
    ((partial sort))  ; we add parens around so -> have plase to insert
   ))
((partial sort) "123")
```

Or you can use `->>` macro, as it is doing same work as `partial` here:

```
((partial str "hello ") "world")

"hello world"
```

and

```
(->> (str "hello ") "world")    ; expands to (str "hello " "world")

"hello world"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `->` macro is defined as:

```
(doc ->)
-------------------------
clojure.core/->
([x & forms])
Macro
  Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  second item in second form, etc.
```

Therefore (apply str) yields an error, because the list from the former function is entered as the second argument:

```
(->
    "123"
    seq
    sort
    reverse
    (apply str))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.core/apply (core.clj:624)
```

Instead one should use the macro ->>, which applies to the last item:

```
clojure.core/->>
([x & forms])
Macro
  Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  last item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  last item in second form, etc.
```

Then the solution with `apply` looks like this:

```
(->>
  "123"
  seq
  sort
  reverse
  (apply str))
=> "321"
```

UPDATE: expanded version of the `->` and `->>`:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(->>
                 "123"
                 seq
                 sort
                 reverse
                 (apply str)))
=> (apply str (reverse (sort (seq "123"))))
```

As you can see from the expanded versions, there's only a difference in how the form (apply str) is interpreted. With `->` the second item is inserted while `->>` inserts the last item.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(->
                 "123"
                 seq
                 sort
                 reverse
                 (apply str)))
=> (apply (reverse (sort (seq "123"))) str)
```

Comment: would you mind expanding these to what they would look like as nested invokations?  to me it seems like ->> (thread-thru/thread-last) works "bottom up" and -> (thread-first) works "top down" but now i'm not so sure.

Comment: They're evaluating the forms in the same order, but the difference lies in where the former expanded terms are inserted; at the second or last position.

Comment: Aha.  so in  something like (apply str) it would jam it in between "apply" and "str" if it was -> ?

Comment: Awesome.  Very clear!  thanks for taking the time to explain that.  Clojure is such a beautiful path of discovery in the ninja arts of parens.