# Threading a data structure through a series of functions with other params from a seq

Tags: clojure

This is an extension to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234501/updating-a-map-data-structure-in-consecutive-function-calls-in-clojure).

The purpose is demonstrated as below:

```
(defn foo
  [x a-map]
  (assoc a-map x "value"))

(defn -main
  [x]
  (let [[x1 x2 x3 ... xn] x]
    (-> {}
        (partial foo x1)
        (partial foo x2)
        (partial foo x3)
        ...
        (partial foo xn))))
```

The complexity of this problem lies that I have to populate a variable number of partial functions so I cannot use `->` nor 'comp'. The real mechanism of the `foo` function is not an `assoc` of course so I cannot simplify the problem as a `zipmap`.

I'm not sure if this matter, but the input argument `x` is actually a cartesian product of two sequences. So each element of `x` is a two-element vector that iterates through the cartesian product space of two sequences. It is generated using a `for` loop, or rather, list comprehension.

What do you suggest to handle this problem? Let me know if I failed to give some important info.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your usage of [thread first `->` macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) is incorrect (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29188854/1202461) for more info). Here is the right syntax using [thread last `->>` macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E):

```clj
(->> {}
     (foo x1)
     (foo x2)
     (foo x3)
     (foo x4))
```

Though, it won't work unless the length of vector `x` is determent.

But you could use [`reduce` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) here to process any sequence of elements:

```clj
(reduce #(assoc %1 %2 "value") {} x)
```

Here is a complete example (with slightly redefined `foo` function):

```clj
(defn foo
  [a-map x] ; reversed order of arguments
  (assoc a-map x "value"))

(defn -main
  [x]
  (reduce foo {} x))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Regarding my way of double nested for loops, is the construction of a cartesian seq before the real data manipulation idiomatic? Or what are the other alternatives to do this?

Comment: Building a cartesian product with a `for` loop before feeding it to `reduce` is a fine solution, because `for` produce a lazy sequence. But make sure not to hold a head of produced lazy sequence.

Comment: But why did you mention nested `for` loops? In Clojure you could produce cartesian product with only one `for` loop.

Comment: You're right, in clojure we have only one `for` form. I mentioned "nested" as in the world of Java. Thanks again. That was very helpful!